# What's the gradle equivalent of having another project in your Java build path in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have an Eclipse workspace that looks like this:

```
workspace/  
  ProjectA/  
    src/  
  ProjectThatDependsOnA/   
    src/
```

In Eclipse, I can go into the Project Properties and edit the java build path of ProjectThatDependsOnA to include "ProjectA". What should I put in my build.gradle in ProjectThatDependsOnA to replicate this behavior in Gradle?

Answer (score 12):

Found the answer to my own question: settings.gradle in ProjectThatDependsOnA should have the line:

```
includeFlat 'ProjectA'
```

and then build.gradle should have:

```
compile project(':ProjectA')
```

Comment: Does this require that ProjectA is also a gradle project?

Comment: Thanks man! Lot of hours spent in Gradle docs until reach yourself answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [multi project builds](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) will do what you're looking for.

Comment: It seems like multi project builds rely heavily on the subprojects being inside the directory of the root project. How do subprojects work in this case, where ProjectA is outside the directory of ProjectThatDependsOnA?

Comment: AFAIK the sub-projects must have a common super project. If not you'll need to treat them as two different projects where you install/upload the artifacts form the first and add artifact dependencies in the other.

Comment: Projects in Gradle Multi Project Build could also be on the same level.
The settings.gradle must have than `includeFlat 'ProjectA','ProjectThatDependsOnA'`.
The settings.gradle could be than in a directory called 'master'. The master-directory must be on the same directory level.